# Reviewing the output log of SAS code

Tags: logging, sas, output

A member in my team is using SAS and their code returns "Errors", "Invalid", "Merge statements", "Uninitialized" and "Warning" statements when the input files are incorrect for whatever reason.

After running the code, I routinely check the output log for these key words using CTRL+F and have to amend my input files accordingly.

As you can imagine, using CTRL+F is quite laborious.

I would like the code to automatically print at the end of the output if there were any of the above statements earlier in the output.

How can I do this? Where can I find information on how to program this?

I'm using SAS 9.1

Comment: I highly recommend upgrading to a newer version, or asking your site to upgrade.  9.1 is about ten years old, and missing some significant features compared to even 9.2, not to mention 9.3 or 9.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgrade to SAS 9.4 and use Enterprise Guide for your programming environment, it has an automatic log parser built in that flags errors/warnings, groups them at the bottom, lets you click to find the code or log where they occur, and gives you counts.

Secondly, if you run your code in batch (right click on .sas file -> submit in batch, or run through a .bat file, or similar) then the log will contain pointers to errors at the end, something like "ERRORS WERE PRINTED ON PAGE 45,46,48,55,56".  Not warnings or notes, just errors.

Finally, many people have written and published online log parsers/analyzers/readers.  Some of those do a similar task to what you request above.  [SasCommunity](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Reading_job_logs) has a good list of them, or use the search engine of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

Consider redirecting your log to a file using `PROC PRINTTO`. From there run this code to find any occurrences of the strings you mentioned:

```
filename logfl "<insert log filename here>" lrecl=32767;
/* Lrecl set high to ensure long lines are captured */

data _NULL_;
  infile logfl;
  input;
  if index (_infile_,'ERROR:') then put _infile_;
  else if index(_infile_,'WARNING') then put _infile_;
  else if index(_infile_,'uninitialized') then put _infile_;
  else if index(_infile_,'Merge statements') then put _infile_;
run;
```

Be sure to match the capitalisation of the strings you're looking for, or simply use `UPCASE()` to bring back any capitalisation, e.g.

```
if index(upcase(_infile_),'UNINITI') then put _infile_;
```

Which would match `Uniniti`, `UNINiTi` etc.

The code will simply print back the lines of interest in the order found in the log. You could further improve the code by:

- Putting the strings into a separate dataset or flatfile (in case you find more things you'd like to look for and want to make the code easier to maintain)
- Print the line number where the string was found (output `_N_` along with `_infile_` - test this first, I'm not sure if `_N_` would map *exactly* to the line number)

Comment: This looks brilliant. Thank-you very much. We shall implement it and I will accept when we get it running.

Comment: No problem, I must admit I haven't programmed in SAS for about 6 months, so if there are any issues just ask and I'll hopefully be able to help.

Comment: You can use `find` instead of `index`, which has the modifier `i` to make it case insensitive.